# Very basic Riemann sum in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers on a Python data frame.

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

I would like to calculate and return a new list, the result of the following calculations...

```
(1 + 2)/2
(2 + 3)/2
(3 + 4)/2
(4 + 5)/2
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: You have a *list* in a `pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: Do you mean pandas Series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really suggest you to take a look over the documentation. A simple loop would solve your problem:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
results = []
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    results.append((a[i]+a[i+1])/2)

print(results)
```

**Output:** `[1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]`

Comment: Thanks.  I did not get that output but very useful and I found a way to get what I needed.